# Dificuldade em ordenar

Tags: c, classificação

Estou fazendo um programa que ordene as palavras, só que se eles tiverem o mesmo tamanho não pode se trocar de lugar, estou empacado nesse parte, o código que eu já tenho

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void coloca(char nomes[][100], char *frase, int *tam);
void ordena(char nomes[][100], int tam);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char nomes[100][100], frase[2501];
  int tam, i, teste;
  scanf("%d", &teste);
  getchar();
  while(teste--)
  {
     tam = 0;
     scanf("%[^\n]", frase);
     coloca(nomes, frase, &tam);
     ordena(nomes, tam);
     printf("%s", nomes[0]);
     for(i = 1; i < tam; i++)
     {
         printf(" %s", nomes[i]);
     }
     printf("\n");
     getchar();
  }
   return 0;
}

void coloca(char nomes[][100], char *frase, int *tam)
{
   char *ptr = strtok(frase, " ");
   while(ptr != NULL)
   {
       strcpy(nomes[(*tam)++], ptr);
       ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
 }

 void ordena(char nomes[][100], int tam)
 {
    int i, j;
    char aux[100];
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
       for(j = i + 1; j < tam; j++)
       {
           if(strlen(nomes[i]) == strlen(nomes[j]))
           {

           }
           else if(strlen(nomes[i]) < strlen(nomes[j]))
           {
              strcpy(aux, nomes[i]);
              strcpy(nomes[i], nomes[j]);
              strcpy(nomes[j], aux);
          }
    }
  }
}
```

Exemplo
entrada
Top Coder comp Wedn at midnight

Saida

midnight Coder comp Wedn Top at

Comment: Pode dar mais exemplos ? Então se todas as strings tiverem o mesmo tamanho nada é alterado ?

Answer (score 3):

O seu problema era no `Selection Sort` estava a fazer uma má implementação do algoritmo. Deverá ter uma variável extra `max`, porque ao fazer a troca o nome com índice `i` ia se perder, não sei se estou explicando bem. Um bom método para perceber era ver o que o seu codigo de ordenação faz passo por passo e descobre o seu erro.

```
void ordena(char nomes[][100], int tam)
{
    int i, j, max;
    char aux[100];
    for(i = 0; i < tam-1; i++)
    {
        max=i;
        for(j = i + 1; j < tam; j++)
        {
            if(strlen(nomes[j]) > strlen(nomes[max]))
                max=j;
        }
        strcpy(aux, nomes[i]);
        strcpy(nomes[i], nomes[max]);
        strcpy(nomes[max], aux);
    }
}
```

O Selection sort é desta forma, acha o minimo/maximo e depois troca.

**[Codigo no ideone](https://ideone.com/SCcI0s)**

---

`Top Coder comp Wedn at midnight`

i=0-> `top`-----j=1->`Coder` (é preciso fazer a troca)

i=0->`Coder`----j=2->`comp` <- Vai perder o indice `i` original, o que vai originar numa má ordenação pelo metodo `selection sort`

---

**Selection Sort**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]